# Use WebRTC to capture media stream from web camera, post the stream to a media server and distribute it from there

Tags: javascript, video, video-streaming, webrtc, scalability

I want to broadcast a video stream to many receivers, lets say 5000 - 15000. I only 
want to use WebRTC to send the media stream from the broadcaster's web camera (`getUserMedia()`) to 
a server (f.e: wowza). Transcode the media stream to HLS and MPEG DASH and distribute 
it to the receivers.

So we have B1 who's stream gets distributed to R1, R2, ..., R5000 over a media server.

As far as i know WebRTC is not designed for one to many architecture. I do not want to use P2P. The main goal would be 
to get rid of flash to access the broadcaster's web camera.

Please note the stream will host adult content and the broadcaster can turn the free stream to private any time. Which means 
nobody but the paying members should have access to it only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WebRTC is designed as many-to-many. But it is not only for getting a stream from the webcam. It also encodes it and sends it over the network. Plus P2P connection.

If you want to achieve what you're saying, I think you can make a P2P connection between the broadcaster and the media server. And in the media server to transform/filter/retransmit the stream.

Or you can get the stream from the webcam, encode it and send it to server. But I think this is more difficult.